# Is a function in a for loop called multiple times?

Tags: python

I want to know if this loop call multiple times "hello".upper() (or any other method/function) while iterating:

```
for i in "hello".upper():  
    #DO SOMETHING
```

Considering that "hello" doesn't change in the loop, would this be better performance wise?:

```
string = "hello".upper()  
for i in string:  
    #DO SOMETHING
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loop target is evaluated only once, after which an iterator is obtained. Then, `next()` on that iterator is called for every iteration of the loop.

You can think of `for a in b` as:

```
_iter = iter(b)  # Evaluates b only ONCE
while True:
    try:
        a = next(_iter)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    # loop body ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument to the for statement is evaluated once. So it won't be executed multiple times.